# Gravitational field neutralization

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, antimatter

For the sake of this question, if gravitons existed, and anti gravitons existed, if a field of anti-gravitons was generated, would it not neutralize the attraction in the area of the field, creating a zone of minimal gravity? 
I understand anti-graviton wouldn't mean anti gravity, but wouldn't the two particles annihilate and reduce the field strength?

Comment: To reopen this question (v1) consider to provide peer-reviewed references for theories with anti-gravity and anti-gravitons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's fairly common for uncharged bosons to be their own antiparticles; this is true of the photon and the Z boson and the Higgs; we believe that it would be true of the graviton too. For this to not be true, gravitons would need to have a new charge that we have not yet discovered in the rest of physics yet.

As for whether two gravitons could annihilate, please note that for any two-particle collision, pure annihilation is inconsistent with conservation of momentum in any frame other than the rest frame, and is always inconsistent with conservation of energy. Rotating the diagram, the same conservation-of-momentum objection forbids any particle spontaneously scattering off the vacuum: all Feynman diagram vertices need to have at least three edges. So we could maybe think about them annihilating to form a Z boson, say,  since that has mass.

This sort of thing is unlikely to happen for a simple reason; the recent gravitational waves observed from black hole mergers were 150 Hz, but these quanta would have an energy that's only around 0.6 pico-electron-volts whereas the Z boson has a mass of 90 giga-electron-volts. So we're talking about a difference of 23 orders of magnitude or so.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, because it introduces me to concepts I haven't learned yet. Great job

Answer (score 1):

No, this would not happen. First of all, the gravitational field doesn't consist of gravitons. You can view the field as a multitude of *virtual* gravitons, but this really is only a mathematical abstruction to describe the behavior of the field. There is no method to "generate" virtual gravitons or anti-gravitons, because neither virtual particles nor virtual anti-particles really exist. This is the difference between real and virtual particles: real particles exist while virtual particles don't exist.

In contrast with the gravitational field, a gravitational wave does consist of real gravitons. Can we generate a wave that consists of anti-gravitons? Yes, but not really, because the graviton is its own anti-particle. So a wave of gravitons and a wave of anti-gravitons are the same thing.

This is very similar to light. Can we create a beam of anti-photons? Sure. It would just be a beam of photons, because the photon also is its own anti-particle. Would two beams of light annihilate? No, they would not, as you know from the everyday experience. Similarly, two beams of gravitons (gravitational waves) may create an interference pattern, but would not annihilate each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a clarification on terms used, too long for a comment.

> For the sake of this question, if gravitons existed, and anti gravitons existed

The three out of four [fundamental forces](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) we know in nature have been described with the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) which unites them  in a mathematical form.

This form has the gauge bosons in the [fourth column](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) and you will notice a question mark against the graviton. That is because *there is no definitive quantization of gravity*. It is under research, and it is hypothesized that it will follow the same path as quantization of the other three forces, so that a unified theory can be attained.

If this happens, then the graviton is the antiparticle of itself, similar to the photon and the gluon and the Z bosons.

If research validates a different quantization of gravity model, then the question of antigravitons possibly different from gravitons might arise. The answers you got are within the standard model of physics at present.

The LIGO experiment verified the existence of classical gravitational waves so your :

> would it not neutralize the attraction in the area of the field, creating a zone of minimal gravity?

Is answered in the affirmative for classical waves, as they will have classical interference patterns , with enhancement and diminution of the classical gravitational field as they pass. In fact that is how they were discovered in [LIGO,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves), by their interference patterns.